# Parse One-To-Many Relationship Update

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, relationship

I am starting out using Parse and I have a simple question regarding Parse object relationships.

I have two classes: `Flight` and `Pilot`.

A Pilot can have many flights, but a Flight may only have on Pilot. So it is a one to many relationship like so:

```
Pilot < ---- >> Flight
```

If I add a `Pilot` to a `Flight` as a pointer object, do I then need to manually add the same `Flight` to the `Pilot` records?

If I am setting up this relationship in the Parse Data Browser, would I need to add the relation at both ends?

Currently, I have added in the data browser, a Relation field to the Pilot called flights. I have also added a Pointer field to the Flight class called pilot. If in my app I set the pilot pointer on my flight object and save it, in the Parse data browser, if I select the relation field on my pilot, it shows no relation to the flight I added the pilot to. Ideas? It seems to work only one way.

Do I only have to add the pilot pointer to my flight and the relation will be made automatically?

Comment: https://www.parse.com/questions/inverse-relationship-support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one-to-many queries to work in Parse, you only need to add the attribute to one side. Either add a `flights` attribute to `Pilot` or a `pilot` attribute to `Flight`. My suggestion would be to add a `pilot` attribute to `Flight` since it will be just a single object rather than a set of objects.

Now, you "can" add both attributes, but that is generally not necessary and Parse will treat them as separate relationships, meaning you will have to manage both directions.

Comment: Thanks for this, makes a lot more sense now. Is it a similar scenario for many to many relations?

Comment: Many-to-many gets a little more complicated. For that, you might want to consider a join table. That is, a table that holds the relationship between the two objects. In your example, your might have a table called "flightAssignment" that consists of a reference to the "flight" and "crew member". That also makes queries easy since you can do thing like: find all flightAssignments where flight=?, or find all flightAssignments where crewMember = ?

Comment: There is no need to use join table. PFRelation works as well, and parse team advise to use it. Join table are necessary when you have some specific info about relation. For example date when the relation was created etc.